# React Router: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: react-router, reactjs, jsx, react-router-redux

I've just started learning React and got stuck at this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
>       at new Router

Here is my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var { Route, Router, IndexRoute } = require('react-router');
var hashHistory = require('react-router-redux')

var Main = require('./components/Main');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>

        </Route>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The tutorial I was following uses React-Router 2.0.0, but on my desktop I'm using 4.1.1. I tried searching for changes but was unsuccessful in finding a solution that worked.

```
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.15.2",
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
"react-router": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8"
```

Comment: You want to use the BrowserRouter component not Router.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The error is because the api in React Router v4 is totally different.
You can try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Main = () => <h1>Hello world</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path='/' component={Main} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

You can review the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to learn how it works now.

[Here](https://github.com/arkgast/react-router-transition-example) I have a repo with routing animation.

And [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rj4mjk3jpm) you can find a live demo.

Comment: Using BrowserRouter instead of Router - this change alone solved my issue of " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
at Router.render". My versions of related npm packages:  "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",

Answer (score 123):

I got the above error message and it was extremely cryptic.  I tried the other solutions mentioned and it didn't work.

Turns out I accidentally forgot to include the `to` prop in one of the `<Link />` components.

Even if the `<Link />` does not require a `to` prop, you simply just add and write it with empty quotes -> e.g. `<Link to="" />`. That will do the trick!

Wish the error message was clearer. A simple `required prop "to" not found` or something similar would have been helpful. Hopefully, this saves someone else who has encountered the same problem some time.

Answer (score 13):

Just make sure that you've added `to` props to `<Link>` otherwise you would also get the same error.

after adding it should look something like this:-

```
<Link to="#">
```

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that the order of import matter and Router should come first

**Incorrect**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

**Correct**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: It's not the order. In the first one, you are using `BrowserRouter` as `Route` and importing `Router` from `react-router-dom` which is incorrect. You should import `Route` from `react-router-dom` and `BrowserRouter` as `Router`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error and I resolved it by **updating `history`** from `2.x.x` to `4.x.x`

> npm install history@latest --save

Answer (score 7):

Just use BrowserRouter as Router, instead of Router

Answer (score 6):

I had a different cause, but the same error and came across this question because of it.  Putting this here in case the same happens for others and it may help.
 The issue for me was that I had updated to `react-router-4` and accessing `pathname` has changed.

**Change:**
*(React-Router-3 & earlier)*

`this.props.location.pathname`

**To:** *(React-Router-4)*

`this.props.history.location.pathname`

Answer (score 5):

The API in React Router v6 has changed from that of v5.

See the accepted answer in the following:
["Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')" when testing pages in the v6 React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859509/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-pathname-when-testing-pages-in)

Answer (score 5):

Check all the Link or NavLink components in your application some of them might be missing the 'to' property which responsible to redirect the user to another path

Answer (score 5):

This error still happen if you pass `undefined` or `null` value to props `to` of `<Link />`.

Answer (score 5):

Use BrowserRouter instead of Router as a wrapper, and don't forget to import BrowserRouter

```
<BrowserRouter>
    // Rest of the app.
</BrowserRouter>
```

This error also arises when u are using Link and forget to mention to="/" prop.

Answer (score 3):

You are giving an undefined value to the "to" props of Link element

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const path = undefined;

function Home() {
  return (
        <Link to={path}>Home</Link> 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In react-router-dom 6+ I'm getting this error

**Error:**

```
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users">
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
   </Routes>
```

**Solution:**

```
<Routes>
   <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
   <Route exact path="/user" element={<User />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: writing exact is not necessary in react-router-dom v6

Comment: Correction: <Route exact> is gone. Instead, routes with descendant routes (defined in other components) use a trailing * in their path to indicate they match deeply. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links

Answer (score 0):

had a similar error showing up when I was trying to use `history.props('./somelink')`. I kept getting the error that the pathname was undefined. Turns out that I was also was using a `<Link></Link>` in my JSX below. This was what was causing the error. Hope this helps for anyone making the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

For react-router v6 you should do this (use element and enclose all routes in `: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70250612/570612

Answer (score 0):

This might helps you in react-router-dom v6

```
import {  BrowserRouter as Router,  Routes,  Route} from "react-router-dom"
```

Answer (score 0):

in some cases you need to define the location props on the main Router like this

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router location={history.location} history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>

    </Route>
</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Edit: history has to be defined with createBrowserHistory() from 'history'

Answer (score 0):

Go to index.js file and wrap `<App/>`  inside `<BrowerRoute>`

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App/>                                                   
</BrowserRouter>
```

and you are done :0

Answer (score 0):

it was not working and giving me this type error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
unfortunately, i was typing mistake the to attribute when i was using NavLink.
you can solve this

try to remember write "to" attribute in the correct way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).