# Shows error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

When i work in react.I have shows "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')" , when i want to side page to page!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620289/react-router-cannot-read-property-pathname-of-undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to the fact that you're trying to access a property (of an object) which is not defined. A possible scenario is when you have an object with a nested structure like this:

```
{
  data: {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    currentJob: {
      location: "US",
      roles: [...],
      previousJob: {
        reference: "a1b2c3",
        quitAt: ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, imagine you're receiving from an API call an object structured like the one above (typical example of an object displaying the account of a user) but for some reasons there is no "previousJob" associated with another user. If you tried to access its "quitAt" property through `data.currentJob.previousJob.quitAt` you'd get a reference error, because you won't find "previousJob" in the first place.

Two steps to take at this point:

1. investigate on the reasons why that property is missing;
2. possibly use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to short-circuit the reference error with a return value of undefined (e.g. `data.currentJob.previousJob?.quitAt`).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620289/react-router-cannot-read-property-pathname-of-undefined

Answer (score 0):

1)This error will disappear if you use (?) optional chaining during fetching of data;

2. Just use - ?. ;

3)Example - data?.fact;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).