# How can I test React Router with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I'm new to testing with jest and I want to test the following code.

```
import React from "react";
import "./ButtonLogin.css";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function ButtonLogin() {
    return (
        <Link to="/login"> <button className="button-login">Iniciar sesión</button></Link>
    )
}

export default ButtonLogin;
```

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render, fireEvent, Link } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ButtonLogin } from './ButtonLogin';

it('routes to a new route', async () => {

  ButtonLogin = jest.fn();

  const { getByText } = render(
    <MemoryRouter ButtonLogin={ButtonLogin}>
      <Link to="/login">Iniciar sesión</Link>
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  fireEvent.click(getByText('Iniciar sesión'));

  expect(ButtonLogin).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login');
});
```

I have performed the following test but it fails and I get the following error in line 9.
routes to a new route

```
"ButtonLogin" is read-only.
```

Comment: Best example that I've found for v6 so far: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `createMemoryHistory` function and `Router` component to test it. Create a memory history with initial entries to simulate the current location, this way we don't rely on the real browser environment. After firing the click event, assert the `pathname` is changed correctly or not.

`ButtonLogin.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function ButtonLogin() {
  return (
    <Link to="/login">
      <button className="button-login">Iniciar sesión</button>
    </Link>
  );
}

export default ButtonLogin;
```

`ButtonLogin.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import ButtonLogin from './ButtonLogin';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
describe('ButtonLogin', () => {
  test('should change current location to login when button is clicked', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ['/home'] });
    const { getByText } = render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <ButtonLogin />
      </Router>
    );
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/home');
    fireEvent.click(getByText('Iniciar sesión'));
    expect(history.location.pathname).toBe('/login');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69878146/ButtonLogin.test.tsx (10.675 s)
  ButtonLogin
    ✓ should pass (41 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 ButtonLogin.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.722 s, estimated 12 s
```

package version: `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"`

Comment: Note that `<Router history={history} />` doesn't work in v6, which is what you currently get when you `npm i react-router-dom`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69859509/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. Good to know. I am still using `react-router` v5

Comment: so what's the way to do this in v6 , any idea @jonrsharpe

Comment: @gaurav5430 did you read the post I linked above?

Answer (score 3):

Late to this, but React Router Dom v6 can handle tests this way.

```
import {BrowserRouter, MemoryRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const reactRouterContext = (children: any) => {

    if (isTest) {
        return <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>{children}</MemoryRouter>
    }

    return <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>

}
```

EDIT - adding implementation per request:

```
const reactRouterContext = (children: any) => {

    if (isTest) {

        return <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>{children}</MemoryRouter>

    }

    if (this.props.browserRouter ?? true) {

        return <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>

    }

    return <HashRouter>{children}</HashRouter>

}

return reactRouterContext(<>
    <Routes>
        {'' === user_id
            ? <>
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
                <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgetPassword/>}/>
                <Route path="/recover-password" element={<RecoverPassword/>}/>
                <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to={'/login'}/>}/>
             </>
             : <Route path="/" element={<Main/>}>
                   <Route path="/sub-menu-2" element={<Blank/>}/>
                   <Route path="/sub-menu-1" element={<SubMenu/>}/>
                   <Route path="/blank" element={<Blank/>}/>
                   <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile/>}/>
                   <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
                   <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to={'/'}/>}/>
              </Route>}
    </Routes>
    <ToastContainer
        autoClose={3000}
        draggable={false}
        position="top-right"
        hideProgressBar={false}
        newestOnTop
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnHover
        />
</>);
```

Comment: Interesting. What's the implementation look like ?

Comment: Nothing changes in your tests; this just enables a non-browser implementation.