# Testing a react component that uses search parameters in the url

Tags: reactjs, vitest

I want to test a react component that reads search params from the url.
This is the component (the full content is sanitized to focus on the main problem) that reads a param from the url `localhost:2000/#/list?ids=001,002`:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function List() {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const idsString = searchParams.get('ids');
  const ids = idsString?.split(',') || [];

  return (
    <div>{ids}</div>
  );
}
```

I am stuck at the point where I have to render the component whilst passing the url params at the same time. Here is my test in vitest:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import List from './List';

describe('List', () => {
  test('show list of ids when provided the ids from the url', async () => {
    render(<List />);
    expect(await screen.findByText('001,002')).toBeInTheDocument());
  });
});
```

How can I include the url params in the test? Will I have to mock `useSearchParams` and how can I mock it if it is the only way?

Comment: I recommend looking into `MemoryRouter` from `react-router-dom`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878146/how-can-i-test-react-router-with-jest and https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/memory-router for more details and suggestions.

Comment: You won't necessarily need to mock `useSearchParams()` directly. But you will need to wrap your `<List/>` in a proper provider (maybe indirectly using a router) for the hook to work correctly in the context of your test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the test, you only instantiate the component itself and do not actually specify/query a URL.
It may be possible to mock the URL, or better only those parameters. But as it stands, your test cannot draw any parameters from the URL.

If you have ***jest*** at hand you can use sth. like:

```js
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useSearchParams: () => [new URLSearchParams({ ids: '001,002' })],
}));
```