# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Tags: reactjs, react-router

(I've reviewed other similar SO posts and haven't found an adequate solution. I have a simple/minimal Github POC of this issue at the bottom of my question).

My project has moved from [`connected-react-router`](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/) to [`redux-first-history`](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history/) as `connected-react-router` doesn't have support for [`react-router` (v6)](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router). My app loads fine, but as soon as I try to navigate to another page I get this error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')`. I can't figure out if this is an error in redux-first-history or somewhere else. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859510/1837080) makes me feel like `<HistoryRouter>` needs to support something like this (but I'm not entirely sure).

**store.js** (with @reduxjs/toolkit)

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createHashHistory, createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { createReduxHistoryContext } from "redux-first-history";

const { routerMiddleware, createReduxHistory, routerReducer } = createReduxHistoryContext({
  history: createHashHistory()
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: combineReducers({
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: false
  }), routerMiddleware]
});

export const history = createReduxHistory(store);
```

**app.js** (react-router v6)

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { HistoryRouter } from "redux-first-history/rr6";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import AppRoutes from "Core/routes";
import Nav from "./nav";
import "./root.css";

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props;
    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <HistoryRouter history={history}>
            <AppRoutes></AppRoutes>
          </HistoryRouter>
        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;
```

**routes.jsx**

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import ROUTES from "Constants/routes";
import loadable from "@loadable/component";

// Load bundles asynchronously so that the initial render happens faster
const Welcome = loadable(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "WelcomeChunk" */ "Pages/welcome/welcome")
);
const About = loadable(() =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "AboutChunk" */ "Pages/about/about")
);

class AppRoutes extends React.Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path={ROUTES.WELCOME} element={<Welcome />}></Route>
        <Route path={ROUTES.ABOUT} element={<About />}></Route>        
      </Routes>
    );
  }
}

export default AppRoutes;
```

**welcome.jsx**

```jsx
import React from "react";
import ROUTES from "Constants/routes";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <section className="section">
          <div className="container">
            <h2 className="title is-2">Samples</h2>
            <div>
              <Link to={ROUTES.ABOUT}>About page</Link> <br />
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

**about.jsx**

```jsx
import React from "react";

class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="section">
          <div className="container">
              <h1 className="title is-1">About</h1>
          </div>          
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

### repro steps

https://github.com/reZach/react-router-v6-upgrade

Comment: If the error comes from 3rd party code and you're reasonably sure you're using it correctly, the best course of action is to raise an issue against the relevant open-source project. _Ed_: which I see you've [already done](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history/issues/83). Just wait for the author to get back to you

Comment: I can clearly see in your [`package-lock.json`](https://github.com/reZach/react-router-v6-upgrade/blob/master/package-lock.json#L6860) that you still have `history@4.10.1`. It's already been pointed out in your issue thread (as well as [this similar one](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history/issues/70)) that you need at least v5.0.0

Comment: Thank you @Phil, I see you have found my post on the open-source project's repo. I have a feeling this issue I see others have too _may_ be a combination of `redux-first-history` _and_ `react-router` which is why I posted here as well. But thank you for your input here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **@Phil**, `npm i history` needed to be ran to install a v5 version of `history` needed to be present to be used with `react-router` v6. [Comment here](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history/issues/70#issuecomment-1063903524).

Comment: Don't thank me, I just read it from the issue on Github