# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can't understand what the problem is

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './views/Home.js'
import Register from './views/Register.js'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header/>
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

```
  278 | }
  279 | 
  280 | let {
> 281 |   pathname = "/",
      | ^  282 |   search = "",
  283 |   hash = "",
  284 |   state = null,
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43620883/311255]) `BrowserRouter`, also include `Switch` inside `Router`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add Switch component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Home from './views/Home.js'
import Register from './views/Register.js'

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

export default App
```