# React : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm readapting my routes but an error appears "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')`" and I can't solve it, I've been going around in circles for hours. I'm fairly new to react.
I think I am using BrowserRouter, Routes, Router incorrectly etc
Can anyone help me ?

errors:

```
  components.tsx:197 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
        at Router (components.tsx:197:1)
        at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
        at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
        at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
        at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)

    react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Router> component:
    
        at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:108514:15)
        at ConnectedRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53802:7)
        at ConnectedRouterWithContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53925:25)
        at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:104929:114)
        at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:104640:5)
    
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Voici **index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import App from "./App";
import { store, history } from './configureStore'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
    (<Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" component={App}/>
            </Routes>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>)
);
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {requests} from "./agent";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router";
import HomePage from "./Pages/HomePage";
import LoginPage from "./Pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./Pages/RegisterPage";
import Dashboard from "./Pages/Dashboard";
import News from "./Pages/News";
import Missions from "./Pages/Missions";
import Associations from "./Pages/Associations";
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');

        if(token) {
            requests.setToken(token)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Navigation  />
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />}/>
                        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />}/>
                        <Route path='/register' element={<RegisterPage />}/>
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please show entire error message with stack trace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620289/react-router-cannot-read-property-pathname-of-undefined)

Comment: Why are you using more than one router? `connected-react-router` isn't compatible with `react-router-dom@6`. Are you looking for a redux connected routing solution that works with `react-router-dom@6`?

Comment: Yes that's it @Drew Reese

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind can you edit post and share your Redux store configuration file/code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `connected-react-router` hasn't updated to be compatible with `react-router-dom@6`, and the author hasn't been active. `connected-react-router` seems to be a dead project. A replacement I've found that works (*IMO*) equally well is [`redux-first-history`](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history).

Basic Setup:

1. Add `redux-first-history` to the project.

   `npm install --save redux-first-history`
2. Create custom history object & Configure Redux store

   ```
   import { combineReducers } from "redux";
   import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
   import { createReduxHistoryContext } from "redux-first-history";
   import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

   const {
     createReduxHistory,
     routerMiddleware,
     routerReducer
   } = createReduxHistoryContext({ history: createBrowserHistory() });

   export const store = configureStore({
     reducer: combineReducers({
       router: routerReducer
     }),
     middleware: [routerMiddleware]
   });

   export const history = createReduxHistory(store);
   ```
3. Import and render correct router

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import { Provider } from "react-redux";
   import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router';
   import { store, history } from './configureStore';
   import App from "./App";

   const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
   root.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <Router history={history}>
         <App />
       </Router>
     </Provider>
   );
   ```

   ...

   ```
   class App extends React.Component{
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       const token = window.localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');

       if (token) {
         requests.setToken(token)
       }
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <>
           <Navigation  />
           <Routes>
             <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />}/>
             <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />}/>
             <Route path='/register' element={<RegisterPage />}/>
           </Routes>
         </>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

*This solution might not work with the new RRDv6.4 Data APIs.*

Comment: It' works !! I just replaced  ```<Router>``` by ```<BrowserRouter>``` in your example and it worked! Thank you very much, you are awesome!

Comment: Is this the right router `import { HistoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router'`? I tried using it but got an error saying it was not a recognized import.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
<BrowserRouter>
```

try using

```
<Router>
```