# Undefined 'pathname' issue with connected-react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

I have a fairly simple React app that I'm having issues getting to work after adding `connected-react-router`. None of the pages will load and it immediately throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')`.

I've tried some solutions mentioned in Git like downgrading the library and made sure NavLinks have the `to` prop as some mentioned that being the issue.
Anyone know how to fix this? I'm at a loss.

```
// App.js

import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import '@enterprise-ui/canvas-ui-css';
import { AuthProvider } from '@praxis/component-auth';
import configureAppStore, { history } from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import './globalStyles/customStyles.scss';
import './globalStyles/rootStyles.scss';
import { Main } from './views/Main';
import apiConfig from './globalConfig/apiConfig';

const initialState = {};
const store = configureAppStore(initialState);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <AuthProvider {...apiConfig.auth}>
          <Main />
        </AuthProvider>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
// store.js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';

import scannerReducer from './scanner/scannerSlice';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default function configureAppStore(preloadedState) {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      router: connectRouter(history),
      scanner: scannerReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware().concat(routerMiddleware(history)),
    preloadedState,
  });

  return store;
}
```

```
// Main.js
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ErrorBoundary } from '@praxis/component-logging';

import { ErrorContent } from '../components/ErrorContent';
import { LayoutSimple } from '../views/LayoutSimple';
import { Homepage } from '../views/Home/Homepage';
import { InstallationPage } from '../views/Installation/InstallationPage';
import { OnboardingPage } from '../views/Onboarding/OnboardingPage';
import { OnboardingForm } from '../views/Onboarding/OnboardingForm/OnboardingForm';
import { ScannerPage } from '../views/Onboarding/Scanner/ScannerPage';
import { LookupPage } from '../views/Lookup/LookupPage';

export const Main = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary key={location.pathname} FallbackComponent={ErrorContent}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />}></Route>
        <Route path="/layout" element={<LayoutSimple />}></Route>
        <Route path="/install" element={<InstallationPage />}></Route>
        <Route path="/onboarding" element={<OnboardingPage />}></Route>
        <Route path="/scan" element={<ScannerPage />}></Route>
        <Route path="/registration" element={<OnboardingForm />}></Route>
        <Route path="/lookup" element={<LookupPage />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

```
// package.json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
"react-redux": "8.0.5",
"connected-react-router": "6.9.3",
"history": "^4.7.2",
```

Comment: `react-connected-router` hasn't been updated to be compatible with `react-router-dom@6`. Does this help answer your question though? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73628683/8690857

Comment: Ugh that sucks. But definitely worth a try! And it looks like it's compatible with redux-toolkit, yes?

Comment: Affirmative, `redux-first-history` totally works with RTK. It was about a 10-minute integration the first time.