# How to redirect from redux (w/ react router v6)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

With react-router 5 I used library - react-connected-router to make redirect from redux store. This library doesnt work with react router 6. How I can implement this?

I can just put navigate from useNavigate to payload and then in store use it. But I think it's not good decision. What can you recommend?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73628683/8690857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just navigate after you have dispatched your `action` to redux? Then you keep your navigation strictly to `ReactComponent`s

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in a function

```
let history = useHistory();

const myActions = () => {
 dispatchAction1()
 dispatchAction2()
 history.push("/MY_ROUTE")
}
```